# Finding a homotopy map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $K=\mathbb R^2\times (-\infty,0)\subset \mathbb R^3$, and let $Q$  be an open connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Is the fundamental group $\pi_1(Q\times [0,1)\cup K)$ trivial? And is it possible to find the retraction explicitly?

Comment: Is there a typo?  Is $W$ supposed to be the same as $Q$?

Comment: @SammyBlack yes, thanks

Comment: Sure.  You can "drag" any loop down into $K$, where it contracts to a point.  I can give a more explicit answer later.

Comment: By the way, to speak of the fundamental *group*, you have to choose a basepoint.  Else, you need the language of the fundamental *groupoid*.

Comment: @SammyBlack, I meant by the fundamental is trivial that the space is contactable. Yes please can you give me an explicit map. I want to see how things are going on.. Thanks a lot indeed.